# How get dynamic query data into CLOB column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to insert the select query data into a CLOB column as a comma-separated value. Below is the anonymous block that I've created to do this. 
I'm using dbms_sql to fetch all the table headers. Now, I want to do the same for the table rows so that it will work with any query. I'm stuck into the logic. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 declare
l_clob  clob;
l_row   varchar2(4000);
v_sql varchar2(32767) := 'select * from all_tables';
out varchar2(6000);
out2 varchar2(6000);
v_cursor_id integer;
v_col_cnt integer;
v_columns dbms_sql.desc_tab;

 begin

    v_cursor_id := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor_id, v_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor_id, v_col_cnt, v_columns);

-- get header data
    for i in 1 .. v_columns.count loop
        out:= v_columns(i).col_name;
         out2:=out2||','||out;
    end loop;
out2:= LTRIM(out2,',') ||chr(10);

 dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, true);


   dbms_lob.writeappend (l_clob, length(out2), out2);

--get table rows

--DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS ??

 -- for i in ( select * from user_tables ) loop

  --l_row := i.table_name||','||i.num_rows||','||i.blocks||chr(10);

 --dbms_lob.writeappend (l_clob, length(l_row), l_row);  end loop;

  insert into convert_clob values ('demo.csv' ,'application/vnd.ms-excel',l_clob );  -- l_clob = clob column
    commit;

dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);


dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
exception when others then
dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
raise;

  end;
  /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this standard procedure to display the result of any dynamic query, with the header.  I have borrowed some of the code from this [Ask TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537323500346032880) post.

```
create or replace procedure return_result( l_query varchar2 )
   is
       l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
       l_columnValue   varchar2(4000);
       l_status        integer;
       l_colCnt        number := 0;
       l_separator     varchar2(1);
       l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   begin
       dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  l_query, dbms_sql.native );

       dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );


           l_separator := '';
           for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
               dbms_output.put( l_separator || l_descTbl(i).col_name );
               l_separator := ',';
           end loop;
           dbms_output.put_line('');

        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
           dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
       end loop;
       l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

       while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
           l_separator := '';
           for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
               dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
               dbms_output.put( l_separator || l_columnValue );
               l_separator := ',';
           end loop;
           dbms_output.new_line;
       end loop;
       dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
   end;
 /
```

Modify it to suit your requirement, something like

```
l_clob := l_clob ||  l_separator || l_descTbl(i).col_name ;
```

for headers, and

```
l_clob := l_clob || l_separator || l_columnValue;
```

for rows

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=16b2357320b5ad6e2bcdda88aff5245c)

Comment: Hi, I've tried this one but it's not working with CLOB! dbms_lob.writeappend (l_clob, length(l_row), l_row);

Comment: @steve : "Not working" is not a problem statement. Describe what error you get, it may be possible to help you.

Comment: Data is getting printed through the dbms_output but when I'm trying to insert the data into the table using l_clob := l_separator || l_columnValue then it's only inserting the single column value.

Comment: @steve : I'm not sure how you've modified it. I've edited my answer and added a demo. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you for doing this but this is not I want. I want the whole values to get inserted into a single column so that later I can use it further for converting into the CSV file. Is there another way around?

Comment: @steve : That will have you no advantage over storing it row-wise. It'll be much simpler to extract later. What you want can be done though, but you will have to slightly tweak the code and use `update` instead of `insert`. I may provide you the whole code. But, I wish you try. My recommendation would be to rethink your design. If you have no other option, storing row-wise  (this solution) is far better than what you're expecting.